# Finger getting twisted with rotation

Tags: mesh, bones, weight-painting, axis

All the fingers in the hand works perfectly, but the middle finger twist in the middle when rotate the bone on Y, the weight paint is correct, but still twists.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should align the orientation of your bones in *Edit* mode with some <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> + *angle value* (I don't know why, technically, it makes it bug when non-aligned though):

[image]

Comment: It worked, i adjusted the roll to 90º